# create samba share with SMBv1 and multiple networks to separate old machine?

Tags: docker, samba, netbios

i have a very specific scenario i'm trying to achieve. I'm using a pretty old machine that relies on SMBv1 AND Netbios Name to find its working data. Currently i'm running a separate computer with windows and two NICs to keep the machine separated from the rest of the network for security measures. Other people need to access the data as well to give the machine new work.

On the windows computer, there is one network with 192.168.178.0/24 and a second one with 192.168.69.0/24. The machine uses 192.168.69.91 and searches for the netbios name PC-MASTER to find its working data. I can't edit the way the machine searches for the share and due to its old windows version it relies on SMBv1 to be enabled.

Is there a way to achieve that with this image? I'm experimenting with different macvlan setups but can't get that to work.

My current docker-compose looks like that:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    container_name: mimot_smb
    hostname: pc-master
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "137:137/udp"
      - "138:138/udp"
      - "139:139/tcp"
      - "445:445/tcp"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /tmp/mimot:/mimot
    command: '-n -S -g "netbios name = pc-master" -g "workgroup = ARBEITSGRUPPE" -s "mimot;/mimot;yes;no;yes" -p'
```

With that one i can find the share on the host but not associated the the netbios name pc-master.

I tried adding a macvlan ignoring the second ip-address first. Just to make sure the netbios is working:
`docker network create --driver=macvlan --gateway=192.168.0.1 --subnet=192.168.0.1/24 --ip-range=192.168.0.215/28 -o parent=eth0 mimot`

and changed the docker-compose accordingly:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    container_name: mimot_smb
    hostname: pc-master
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
    networks:
      - mimot
    ports:
      - "137:137/udp"
      - "138:138/udp"
      - "139:139/tcp"
      - "445:445/tcp"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /tmp/mimot:/mimot
    command: '-n -S -g "netbios name = pc-master" -g "workgroup = ARBEITSGRUPPE" -s "mimot;/mimot;yes;no;yes" -p'

networks:
  mimot:
    external: true
```

With that, the container gets assigned its own ip-adress but the netbios is still not working. I cant get it to work to have multiple ip-addresses AND the netbios working.

Do you have any help on that front?

**Edit:
To make it clear: It is not needed that windows lists the server under network but it must be accessible by \\pc-master\mimot\

** Edit2:
The current setup:
First System is the old machine, ip 192.168.69.91
Second System is a PC for the operator, ip 192.168.178.0/24

The server is a supermicro with VMWare ESXi 7.0:
One VM on Windows with multiple NICs (192.168.69.90 and 192.168.178.0/24) with enabled SMBv1 support and the needed share. The old machine is directly connected to one of the supermicro NICs to separate the machine from the rest of the network. The other NIC is connected to a Netgear GS748T to make the share accessible over the network.

A second VM with PhotonOS where i'm using docker to deploy additional services like ERPNext, a self developed internal system, traefik, pi-hole, etc.

Comment: Does it have to be NetBIOS name service? What happens if you define "pc-master" in your local DNS?

Comment: the machine hasn't got access to the local DNS. It is based on an old windows NT and has to be separated from the network. It hast just an ip address set (192.168.69.91) and thats it.

Comment: Windows NT definitely supported DNS for this purpose (as well as WINS and the LMHOSTS.TXT file)... What networks is your Docker system on? What IP address does it get when you use the macvlan mode? Do you see it sending NetBIOS broadcasts on UDP ports 137, 138? (I'm not familiar with Docker, but it doesn't make sense to me that you're specifying 'ports:' or '--gateway' in macvlan mode at all...) Is it from 192.168.69.0/24?

Comment: i think you are correct that using the mavclan network the ports part is not needed. I'm checking for the netbios broadcasts next. I'm going to edit the question and add additional info to the hardware used.